# is a function differentiable at the point

Tags: differential

$G(x,y)=(x^2+y,xy+x^2)$, $P=(a,b)$ is G differentiable at P? calculate dG(P)

Attempt:

I think I understand how to find dG(P) it is just,
$dG(P) = (2a,b)$ correct?

I am needing help how I show that G is differentiable at P.

Comment: Since $G: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, you must have $DG(P): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, so the above cannot be correct as it must be a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: @copper.hat I see I think I calculated dG(P) incorrectly it is supposed to be 2a+b, meaning it goes from $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$.  Is there a way to show it is not differentiable by any other means?

Comment: It **is** differentiable, but the derivative is a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: which derivative are you talking about? Gradient, or divergence? or exterior derivative ?

Comment: @mastrok I am positive the question is talking about the gradient.  Agh, I am getting gradient and divergence mixed up.